# C# generics: How to pass current class's type as a para

Tags: c#, generics

I would like to

1. Move my OnModelCreating to the base class and
2. Call `modelBuilder.Entity<T>` without explicitly specifying the T.  I would just like to say, the 'current class' (meaning in this example `UserType` as it is `UserType` on which the index needs creating)

```cs
public class BaseLookupEntity : BaseEntity
{
    [Key()]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public override int Id { get; set; }

    //...

}

public class UserType: BaseLookupEntity
{
    internal static void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // unique 
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserType>()
            .HasIndex(c => c.Enum)
            .IsUnique();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class someBaseClass
{
    public void Foo<TInferrConcreteDerivedTypeCallingThisMethodHere>()
}
```

No, thats not possible, and if you understand how generics works you'd see why. Generic types are not resolved at runtime (excluding `dynamic` and reflection scenarios), all generic type parameters are resolved at compile time. Therefore, there is no way the compiler can know what the real type of `TInferrConcreteDerivedTypeCallingThisMethodHere` is from within `SomeBaseClass` without running the code.

Inheritance is a red herring here, the same issue arises with the classical example of statically unknown types:

```
void Foo<T>(T t) { ... }

object o = GetSomeRuntimeObjectIDontKnowTheTypeOf();
Foo(o); T is inferred
```

Can you guess what `T` is inferred to? You can narrow it down to two options: `Foo<RuntimeTypeOfUnkownObject>` or `Foo<object>`? If you have doubts, run it and figure it out.

Also, as far as type inference goes, a rule of the thumb, whenever you have a generic method with a signature similar to:

```
void Foo<T>(/*no arguments from which T can be inferred*/)
```

or even

```
T Foo<T>(/*no arguments from which T can be inferred*/)
```

`T` can not or will not be inferred.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to make your base class generic as well in that case

```
public class BaseLookupEntity<T> : BaseEntity where T : BaseLookupEntity<T>
{
    [Key()]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public override int Id { get; set; }

    internal static void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // unique 
        modelBuilder.Entity<T>()
            .HasIndex(c => c.Enum)
            .IsUnique();
    }
}

public class UserType: BaseLookupEntity<UserType>
{
}
```

Comment: That's just pushing the problem a step up. He'll still have to explicitly say what `T` is, which is what he seems to want to avoid. Not saying its possible though... this seems an XY problem unless he just wants to avoid typing the few extra keystrokes.

Comment: @InBetween I've possibly misconstrued the problem, I thought the OP was just looking to move the code into somewhere common so they don't have to keep overriding `OnModelCreating` when deriving new types.

Answer (score 0):

There is in-built support for decoupled (from DB context) configurations. Your configuration class must implement `IEntityTypeConfiguration<T>` [interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.ientitytypeconfiguration-1?view=efcore-3.0).

Then you can easily apply configurations inside your `DbContext`'s `OnModelCreating` method using `ApplyConfiguration<T>` [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.modelbuilder.applyconfiguration?view=efcore-3.0).

Your example, could look like:

```
public class CustomDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration<UserTypeConfiguration>(new UserTypeConfiguration());
    }
}

public class UserTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<UserType>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<UserType> builder)
    {
        builder
            .HasIndex(c => c.Enum)
            .IsUnique();
    }
}
```

Note: I can't try your inheritance chain, but it should work out of the box, if you do:

Answer (score 0):

Using generics, you can't.

Generics are evaluated at compile time, but as your base class will have multiple sub classes, the type will only be known at runtime.

There is an overload for [ModelBuilder.Enity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.modelbuilder.entity?view=efcore-3.0#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_ModelBuilder_Entity_System_String_) that accepts a System.Type object, which can be used at runtime, so you could use that in your base class.

Personally i would do this in your DbContext and list all the base classes individually e.g.

```
private void MapLookupEntitity<TLookup>(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) where TLookup : BaseLookupEntity
{
    // unique 
    modelBuilder.Entity<TLookup>()
        .HasIndex(c => c.Enum)
        .IsUnique();
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    MapLookupEntitity<UserType>(modelBuilder);
    MapLookupEntitity<AnotherType>(modelBuilder);
    // map some more..
}
```